# Css make element behind sibling of grandparent

Tags: html, css, layout, z-index

[This pen has my code.](https://codepen.io/laurenceks/pen/RwVKXzz)

I need to get ````` div.header.bg```` to render at the bottom behind everything, then ````` div.page.bg``` in front and then all the other content 'normally`. I have tried various z-indexes but can't get my head around the stacking context.

Happy to make alterations but I'm limited by `div.header.bg` which needs to stay where it is so that its height matches its parent (plus a bit to get it to the middle of the search bar).

Here's the code from the pen - I've take out any z-index or non-layout positioning to make it a 'blank canvas' - can anyone help? None of then solutions on similar topics have worked, possibly as they're simpler strucutres (child behind parent)

**html**

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="pageWrap m-3">
            <div class="page bg"></div>
            <div class="mainWrap container-fluid d-flex flex-column justify-content-center px-5">
                <div class="headerWrap w-100 text-center p-5">
                    <div class="header bg"></div>
                    <div class="header mx-auto">
                        <h1 class="mt-5 mb-3" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">ePCR Case Reference Validator</h1>
                        <p class="my-3">This is a simple tool for validating ePCR case references</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="searchContainer w-100 d-flex justify-content-center p-3 position-relative">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Enter the ePCR case reference here" maxlength="12" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**css (scss)**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

//variable overwrites

$bgBorderRadius: 20px;
$underScoreBorderWidth: 0.2rem;

$easeOutCirc: cubic-bezier(0, 0.55, 0.45, 1);


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #353b48 !important;
}

div.pageWrap {
  max-width: 720px;
}

div.pageWrap {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

div.page.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f5f6fa;
  border: 1px solid #dcdde1;
  backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  border-radius: $bgBorderRadius;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


div.searchContainer {
}

div.searchContainer > input {
  height: 4rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.25rem;
}

div.searchContainer > input::placeholder {
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: initial;
  letter-spacing: initial;
  color: gray;
}

div.headerWrap, div.header {
  position: relative;
}

div.header.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  left: min(0px, calc((100% - 100vw) / 2));
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100% + 4rem);
  background-color: #40739e;
  background-image: url("https://products.ls.graphics/mesh-gradients/images/25.-Witch-Haze_1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

p.resultString {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

p.resultString span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span.letter {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

span.letter.letterMatch {
  position: relative;
}

span.letter > span.letterCaret {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  content: "";
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

div.stringUnderscore {
  height: 1rem;
  border: $underScoreBorderWidth solid;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  ////move left by one padding + one border width
  ////padding: 0 0.25rem;
  //box-sizing: content-box;
  //transform: translateX(-0.45rem);
  transition: left 400ms $easeOutCirc, width 400ms $easeOutCirc, border-color 400ms $easeOutCirc;
}

.stringUnderscore:after {
  content: "";
  height: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: $underScoreBorderWidth solid;
  border-left-color: inherit;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - (#{$underScoreBorderWidth} / 2));
  transition: border-left-color 400ms $easeOutCirc;
}

.stringUnderscoreText {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 200%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

div.resultIcon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.resultIcon > svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p.iconText {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why you put the mention div, in that position, but it wont work nesting so deep. I simply move it up in the document tree, and that way it works. Please let me know if that helps you.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

//variable overwrites

$bgBorderRadius: 20px;
$underScoreBorderWidth: 0.2rem;

$easeOutCirc: cubic-bezier(0, 0.55, 0.45, 1);


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #353b48 !important;
}

div.pageWrap {
  max-width: 720px;
}

div.pageWrap {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

div.page.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f5f6fa;
  border: 1px solid #dcdde1;
  backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(16px) saturate(180%);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  border-radius: $bgBorderRadius;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


div.searchContainer {
}

div.searchContainer > input {
  height: 4rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.25rem;
}

div.searchContainer > input::placeholder {
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: initial;
  letter-spacing: initial;
  color: gray;
}

div.headerWrap, div.header {
  position: relative;
}

div.header.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  left: min(0px, calc((100% - 100vw) / 2));
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100% + 4rem);
  background-color: #40739e;
  background-image: url("https://products.ls.graphics/mesh-gradients/images/25.-Witch-Haze_1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

p.resultString {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

p.resultString span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span.letter {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

span.letter.letterMatch {
  position: relative;
}

span.letter > span.letterCaret {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  content: "";
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

div.stringUnderscore {
  height: 1rem;
  border: $underScoreBorderWidth solid;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  ////move left by one padding + one border width
  ////padding: 0 0.25rem;
  //box-sizing: content-box;
  //transform: translateX(-0.45rem);
  transition: left 400ms $easeOutCirc, width 400ms $easeOutCirc, border-color 400ms $easeOutCirc;
}

.stringUnderscore:after {
  content: "";
  height: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: $underScoreBorderWidth solid;
  border-left-color: inherit;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - (#{$underScoreBorderWidth} / 2));
  transition: border-left-color 400ms $easeOutCirc;
}

.stringUnderscoreText {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 200%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

div.resultIcon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.resultIcon > svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p.iconText {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="header bg"></div> <!-- just move it here -->  
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="pageWrap m-3">
            <div class="page bg"></div>
            <div class="mainWrap container-fluid d-flex flex-column justify-content-center px-5">
                <div class="headerWrap w-100 text-center p-5">
                    
                    <div class="header mx-auto">
                        <h1 class="mt-5 mb-3" data-unsp-sanitized="clean">ePCR Case Reference Validator</h1>
                        <p class="my-3">This is a simple tool for validating ePCR case references</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="searchContainer w-100 d-flex justify-content-center p-3 position-relative">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Enter the ePCR case reference here" maxlength="12" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```